# What is a word that refers to both captions and subtitles?

Tags: single-word-requests

As discussed in this article (https://video.ibm.com/blog/streaming-video-tips/closed-captioning-vs-subtitles/), "subtitles" refers to a dialogue translation that is usually in a different language than the original film, and "captions" (closed or open) are meant for people who aren't able to listen to the audio in a film, and are usually in the same language as the original film.

Does anyone know a good word that encompasses both "subtitles" and "captions"? I would like something that communicates I'm not only referring to one of the two.

I thought this question ([Is "Most of the world does not distinguish captions from subtitles" true?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58044/is-most-of-the-world-does-not-distinguish-captions-from-subtitles-true)) might help me a bit but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *closed-captioning* is a form of *subtitling* so the word you're looking for is *subtitles*. Note that *captions* is a much wider term.

Comment: The Wikipedia article does explain this so why ask it here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_captioning#Terminology [closed means you have to turn it on.] If you are writing a paper, I suggest using subtitles/close- or open-captions.

Answer (score -1):

Captions and subtitles are generally provided by different technologies, so there is no common word in use for both. Subsequently, if you were to find such a word (as on this page [http://www.autocaption.com/captioning_types_of.html], which uses "captioning" for both) then you'll potentially encounter confusion, depending on the community you are communicating with, where such a word is not in common use.

Answer (score -2):

***[text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_captioning#Terminology)***

> Closed captioning (CC) and subtitling are both processes of displaying text on a television, video screen, or other visual display to provide additional or interpretive information.
>   …
>   Most of the world does not distinguish captions from subtitles. … The United Kingdom, Ireland, and most other countries do not distinguish between subtitles and closed captions and use "subtitles" as the general term. The equivalent of "captioning" is usually referred to as "subtitles for the hard of hearing".

Cf. *alt-text* for images.

Answer (score -2):

As descriptive nouns, they are "**audiovisuals**" (audiovisual aids). They *both* can also be considered as "**translations**" (translational aids.), but it is more suggestive of "subtitles" as you mentioned in the question. The dialog, in either case, is being transcribed, so "**transcriptions**" (transcriptional aids) might work as well.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/audiovisual

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/translation

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transcriptions

Comment: None of these terms relates to subtitles or closed-captioning.

Comment: Sorry then, I completely missed your question. I thought you wanted alternative words to describe or use in place of "subtitles or closed-captioning"

Comment: It's not my question. And none of these terms can be used to describe or replace *subtitles* or *closed-captioning*. *Transcription* is a piece of paper (or a text document). *Translation* is content that may be used to produce subtitles. *Audio-visual* is an adjective used to describe types of media.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - a *transcription* may also be sheet music (on paper or on screen), not just text. If you display a transcription on-screen line by line in sync with the audio, what would you call that?